# Do American Christian Universities and Colleges offer as high quality education as other countries?

Tags: application, university

I'm asking specifically about Science courses.

The Kurt Wise case does not reflect on Harvard though it's a Christian University, I understand that. He rejected it because he was convinced geology was biblical, not actual.

It's just that since high school (a few years after 9th grade, translated), the factor in common in discourse has been that proponents making claims incompatible with what I've learned all have Christian Universities as their Alma Mater.

I'm from Sweden and can study in the United States, anywhere in EU, and Switzerland but not Norway.

I would like to finish my studies in the United States. Am I being overly cautious? Are there differences as to what I will be taught, depending on which University?

My application would be for geology with archaeology as minor.

Comment: Harvard is a Christian university?  I mean sure, it was _founded_ as such, but in what sense is it still?

Comment: It's hard to speak in generalities, so won't hazard an answer. But there are certainly examples in both directions. Notre Dame, Georgetown, and Boston College come to mind as Catholic colleges with excellent reputations; I seriously doubt religion affects their science classes. At smaller, less well known colleges, I would likely share your concerns. Then there are schools like BYU, which have a fairly good academic reputation but rather strict moral codes that students are obliged to follow (e.g., no beards without a beard waiver).

Comment: The big ones participate in the same rankings, research, and recruitment competitions as everyone else. It's a big diverse pool but a very competitive one. You can trust the metrics as much as for any other school.

Comment: The statement that Harvard is a Christian university is incorrect. In the US there are private universities that are not religious.

Comment: Uppsala University was also founded as a Christian university.

Comment: Indeed - the fact that Princeton was founded by Presbyterians to train ministers is pretty meaningless 273 years later. Dickinson College, though chartered by the Pennsylvania legislature, is a private non-denominational college.

Answer (score 5):

Christian universities in the United States are tremendously diverse.  The fact that a particular university is "Christian" tells you only that it is not a government owned university.  Almost no other conclusions can be drawn from a Christian identity.

Each university makes its own curriculum.  A science department at one university may exclusively teach science based on religious beliefs.  A science department at another "christian" university might not employ anyone who knows anything about christianity.

Comment: In part, this is because Christianity in the United States is tremendously diverse.  The fact that someone is Christian tells you almost nothing about what he or she believes (perhaps beyond a few abstract theological statements whose application to anything else varies greatly).

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Even then it might not tell you much, depending on your definition of Christianity- for instance, the Mormons consider themselves Christians, even though they don’t adhere to the Nicene Creed, which was literally written as a definition of “what counts a Christianity” within a handful of years after the Roman Empire decriminalised it.